# pdftotext on Centos 6 64bit?

Tags: centos, hosting, pdftotext, xpdf, centos6

I have a HostGator VPS server, and want to be able to run `pdftotext`, part of `xpdf` (http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html).

After testing this out on my Mac, it worked fine, so I went to installing it on my VPS server.

I followed the installation instructions and it all isntalled flawlessly:

> 1. Copy the executables (xpdf, pdftotext, etc.) to to /usr/local/bin.
> 2. Copy the man pages (*.1 and *.5) to /usr/local/man/man1 and    /usr/local/man/man5.
> 3. Copy the sample-xpdfrc file to /usr/local/etc/xpdfrc

Then I tested it out:

```
root@*** [~]# pdftotext
pdftotext: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.11' not found (required by pdftotext)
```

So as you can see, it couldn't find `/lib64/libc.so.6`. `/lib64/libc.so.6` is there, however, as shown by this:

```
root@*** [~]# /lib64/libc.so.6
GNU C Library stable release version 2.5, by Roland McGrath et al.
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Compiled by GNU CC version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52).
Compiled on a Linux 2.6.9 system on 2012-03-19.
Available extensions:
        The C stubs add-on version 2.1.2.
        crypt add-on version 2.1 by Michael Glad and others
        GNU Libidn by Simon Josefsson
        GNU libio by Per Bothner
        NIS(YP)/NIS+ NSS modules 0.19 by Thorsten Kukuk
        Native POSIX Threads Library by Ulrich Drepper et al
        BIND-8.2.3-T5B
        RT using linux kernel aio
Thread-local storage support included.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/bugs.html>.
```

I then contacted HostGator, where they told me that it will not work on my server, as it can't find `/lib64/libc.so.6`, and is therefor not available on Centos 6 64bit.

If this is indeed true, are there any alternatives to `pdftotext` that do a simple and fast conversion that would work on this server? Is it possible that the `pdftotext` can be complied for a different version, or that I installed it incorrectly with permissions?

Comment: CentOS ships pdftotext, so install that. Some other binary not made for CentOS or your particular CentOS version apparently does not work.

Comment: @nos Where would I find this version?

Comment: `poppler-utils` from base repo in centos 7 provides `/usr/bin/pdftotext`

Comment: I simply used "yum install xpdf", which worked fine for me, but it's required to install the EPEL repo first

Comment: @buley I installed `poppler-utils`, but it has version 0.26.5 of `pdftotext`. How to get the newer version (version 4.0)?

Comment: `Xpdf` version that I downloaded from [Glyph & Cog](https://www.glyphandcog.com/opensource.html) gives the latest version (download [link](https://xpdfreader-dl.s3.amazonaws.com/xpdf-tools-linux-4.00.tar.gz)).

Answer (score 1):

Neither of these commands will work:

```
yum install xpdf
yum install poppler-utils
```

xpdf will install poppler-utils anyway and this will result in this pdftotext

> pdftotext version 0.26.5
> Copyright 2005-2014 The Poppler Developers - http://poppler.freedesktop.org
> Copyright 1996-2011 Glyph & Cog, LLC

This is not the version you want. You want this one:

> pdftotext version 4.03 [www.xpdfreader.com]
> Copyright 1996-2021 Glyph & Cog, LLC

This will require going to [www.xpdfreader.com](http://www.xpdfreader.com) and then clicking on "Download". Use the latest versions from this page to set up the newer pdftotext command.

I actually compiled the sources myself:

```
cd /tmp
wget https://dl.xpdfreader.com/xpdf-4.03.tar.gz
tar -xf xpdf-4.03.tar.gz
cd xpdf-4.03
mkdir build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

If successful you should see:

> -- Configuring done
> -- Generating done
> -- Build files have been written to: /tmp/xpdf-4.03

Then just type:

```
make
```

It should end with:

> [100%] Built target pdftotext

Then type

```
make install
```

Now when you type pdftotext you should see:

> pdftotext version 4.03 [www.xpdfreader.com]
> Copyright 1996-2021 Glyph & Cog, LLC

Note: I wrote all my code for pdftotext version 4.03. Took me a while to realise 4.03 and 0.26 produce vastly different results.

Comment: poppler-utils is better due 33 packet dependecy rather than 100 packet of xpdf :)